# Winning and loosing with roulette wheel

Tags: python

```
#This is a roulette wheel

import random 
import time
#Randomiser
green = [0]
red = [1,3,5,7,9,11,13,15,17,19,21,23,25,27,29,31,33,35]
black = [2,4,6,8,10,12,14,16,18,20,22,24,26,28,30,32,34,36]
spin = random.randint (0,36)
#Program
bet = int(input("Enter your Bets: "))
colour = input("Pick your Colour: ")
print ("The wheel is spinning")

if spin in green:
    print ("The ball stopped on green")
    print ("You won",bet*100,"!")

if spin in red:
    print ("The ball stopped on red")
    print ("You won",bet*2,"!")

if spin in black:
    print ("The ball stopped on black")
    print ("You won",bet*2,"!")
```

It tells if someone won. But it can't tell if someone lost. I've been learning python for a couple of months and was wondering if anyone can help me out. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I do not know the rules for roulette, but it seems like you have coded it to always print "congrats you won!"

First you need to assign the players choice (colour) to a testable value, which in our case is the lists you set up:

```
if "red" in colour:
    colour = red
```

you would obviously add the other colors here.

next you need to test the player's choice against the spin value, something like this will work, you will obviously need to modify it to fit your program though:

```
if spin in colour:
    print("you win")
else:
    print("you lose")
```

then modify win results as necessary

Answer (score 0):

It looks like aside from `0`, odd numbers are red and even numbers are green. So this would work even better for you:

```
import random

bet = int(input("Enter your Bets: "))
colour = input("Pick your Colour: ")
print ("The wheel is spinning")

spin = random.randrange(0,37)

if spin == 0:
    print ("The ball stopped on green")
    print ("You won",bet*100,"!")

print ("The ball stopped on", ['black', 'red'][spin%2])
elif ['black', 'red'][spin%2] == color:
    print ("You won",bet*2,"!")
else:
    print ("You lost!")
```

Answer (score -1):

```
if spin in green:
    winning_color = "green"
    print("The ball landed on", winning_color)
if spin in red:
    winning_color = "red"
    print("The ball landed on", winning_color)
if spin in black:
    winning_color = "black"
    print("The ball landed on", winning_color)

if winning_color == colour:
    print("Congrats you won!")
    print("You won", bet*2, "!")

else:
    print("Sorry you lose")
```

Something to be aware of, you should use

```
if somethingHappens:
    doSomething
elif somethingElseHappens:  #Stands for else if, must be after the first if
    doThisInstead
else:  #This is Pythons catchall if the conditions above fail, this will run
    doThisIfNothingElse
```

Comment: Lol my first answer and I messed it up.

Comment: Thank you for explain loops. That's one thing I didn't understand in class. Thanks!